# Routing between two same network (Windows 10) with two computers

Tags: networking, ip

[image: Network image]

I have two separate networks, each network has exactly the same configuration.

The first network has one PC and one IP camera.
The second network has again one PC and one IP camera.

1. Network

- PC 1. Ethernet port 192.168.0.201 connected to the IP camera 192.168.0.120
- PC 2. Ethernet port 192.168.2.110 connected to the second PC (second network)

2. Network

- PC 1. Ethernet port 192.168.0.201 connected to the IP camera 192.168.0.120
- PC 2. Ethernet port 192.168.2.111 connected to the first PC (first network)

Two PC's are connected between (**192.168.2.110 <-> 192.168.2.111**) and each PC has a connection with IP camera (**192.168.0.201 <-> 192.168.0.120**)

My question is:

Is it possible to get an image from second network IP-camera to the PC1 in the first network?

I have no chance to change IP addresses of the cameras. And no chance to add router.

Do I have a chance to create a different 3rd virtual network and reach IP-camera from the second network with 192.168.3.120 (for example) from PC1?

Comment: Are the two PCs actually directly connected as per your diagram or are they separated? Same question for the cameras, do they connect directly to the relevant PCs? Otherwise you might want to be clearer about how the networks are set up. Are there routers separating them, are they at different sites?

Comment: Port forward could be an easy solution to this. What network protocols (TCP/UDP/…) are involved?

Comment: PCs are directly connected. Also, cameras connect directly to the relevant PCs.
The network protocol is TCP.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the MAC address of the second network IP-camera,
you might be able to assign it a dummy IP address in PC1 using `arp`.

An example from the post
[Connecting directly to another computer knowing only the MAC address?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309546/connecting-directly-to-another-computer-knowing-only-the-mac-address/400980#400980)

> IF you can connect to the device you know the MAC of on the same
> network (ideally a cross-over cable).  You can assign an IP address to
> the MAC and then access the IP that way:
>
> **Microsoft Windows** Windows systems require the dash "-" character between each digit of the MAC Address (Ethernet Address).
>
> ```
> arp -s 192.168.1.2 00-80-77-31-01-07
> ping 192.168.1.2
> ```
>
> **UNIX/Linux** UNIX and Linux systems require the colon ":" character between each digit of the MAC Address (Ethernet Address).
>
> ```
> arp -s 192.168.1.2 00:80:77:31:01:07
> ping 192.168.1.2
> ```
>
> For this to work though, you must be on the same Ethernet segment
> (that is, there cannot be a router between you and the device you're
> trying to connect with).

Comment: This won’t work for two reasons: The devices are not on the same broadcast segment, so the MAC address cannot “do” anything. Devices also do care about the IP address in the destination field. If it’s not their own and the device is not a router, the packet will be dropped (+ ICMP “response” sent).

Comment: @DanielB: (1) The devices are directly connected, so they must be on the same broadcast segment. (2) If IP is a problem (I'm not sure about it), the same trick can be used to remap the IP address of camera 1A, leaving camera 1B as `192.168.0.120`. Some manipulations of the routing table might be required, but I think this is a promising direction for finding an answer.

Comment: They aren’t directly connected. PC 1 is connected only to camera 1, but OP wants to access camera 2.

Comment: @DanielB: That's assuming that PC2 won't pass the arp request or pass the following messages if arp succeeds. I really don't know the answers for this, only trying will tell.